# How do you drag to select multiple table cells on mobile?

Tags: select, drag-and-drop, touch

I know this has been asked in different ways but I cannot find a solution to this.
How do I drag to select multiple cells in a table on a mobile device?

What I mean is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Brv6J/3/, but on a mobile device.

Here is the method that I am after:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                $(function () {
                    var isMouseDown = false;
                    $("#our_table td")
                        .mousedown(function () {
                            isMouseDown = true;
                            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
                            return false; // prevent text selection
                        })
                        .mouseover(function () {
                            if (isMouseDown) {
                                $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
                            }
                        })
                        .bind("selectstart", function () {
                            return false; // prevent text selection in IE
                        });

                    $(document)
                        .mouseup(function () {
                            isMouseDown = false;
                        });
                });
            </script>
```